# Using Constants for Mutation Types with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

Consider the approach of using **constants for mutation types** on the Vuex Store that can be seen on this link [Mutation Types - Vuex Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types)

In my project, I've already used such type organization, but I'm migrating to **Nuxt.js** framework. 
That said, the question is: **how can I use that approach on the store of a Nuxt project?**

Comment: You should use constants in nuxt in your vuex store. Nuxt gives you a simple and powerful way to organise your store as you can see in the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#modules-mode).

Comment: @Andrew1325 In my old project I have a type.js that export all the constants. Considering the Nuxt architecture, where should I place that type.js file ?